# how do I add a third column in a first dataframe and place the values from some column of a second dataframe whose ID matches the one in the first DF?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframes `df1` and `df2` (the true ones have around a million rows):

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(23425, 84733, 49822, 39940), X=c(312,354,765,432))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(23425, 49822), Y=c(111,222))
```

And I want to add an additional column Z in dataFrame df1. Each time an ID from df1 match with some ID from df2, the corresponding Y value must be added to that third row. If there is no match, a zero must be added

The result must be this one:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(23425,84733, 49822, 39940), X=c(312,354,765,432), Z=c(111,0,222,0))
```

I stored the ID's from the second dataframe in a vector and used a loop, but it takes forever.

Comment: We can use `match` , `df2$Y[match(df1$ID, df2$ID)]` and then replace `NA` with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is a join:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2)

#> Joining, by = "ID"
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      ID     X     Y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 23425   312   111
#> 2 84733   354    NA
#> 3 49822   765   222
#> 4 39940   432    NA
```

If you want it exactly the way you have it with a new column name and zeroes instead of `NA`, you can add a few more lines:

```r
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    left_join(df2) %>%
    rename(Z = Y) %>%
    replace_na(replace = list(Z = 0))

#> Joining, by = "ID"
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      ID     X     Z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 23425   312   111
#> 2 84733   354     0
#> 3 49822   765   222
#> 4 39940   432     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` to do a join and replace the NA with 0

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, Z := Y, on = .(ID)][is.na(Z), Z:= 0]
df1
#     ID   X   Z
#1: 23425 312 111
#2: 84733 354   0
#3: 49822 765 222
#4: 39940 432   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this simply with merge. Merge will match the Y values in df2 by "ID" to df1. If you specify the "all = TRUE" argument, when no match in df2 is found for IDs in df1, the Y value will be NA.

## merge the 2 datasets by ID and keep all values in each dataset.

> df <- merge(df1, df2, by = "ID", all = TRUE)
>   df
>        ID   X   Y
>   1 23425 312 111
>   2 39940 432  NA
>   3 49822 765 222
>   4 84733 354  NA

## If you want no match to be specified by 0 instead of NA, just replace that value in the Y column.

> df$Y <- ifelse(is.na(df$Y), 0, df$Y)
>   df
>        ID   X   Y
>   1 23425 312 111
>   2 39940 432   0
>   3 49822 765 222
>   4 84733 354   0